# C /CLI datatable AsEnumerable not found

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am trying to use the AsEnumerable extension method on a DataTable in .Net in C++/CLI and Intellisense cannot find it. I already added System.Data.DataSetExtensions to the references of the projects. But it didn't change anything.

When I try the same thing in C#, it is working fine.

Is it possible to use AsEnumerable in C++/CLI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods are not supported in C++/CLI.  You must call the methods as normal methods  In your case, `System::Data::DataTableExtensions::AsEnumerable(dataTable)`.

Comment: Thank you for this quick reply.